# Create ImageView from data, java android

Tags: java, android

I have data that represents an image and I want to create an ImageView

Exemple of image data :
zCH5BAAAAAAALAAAAADIABQAAAT/8MlJq7046827/2AojmRpnmiqrmzrvnAsz1ji3ARK3AMGOIbUgUYsjhA3RwFVuA0tO8ezpBj0jNgshpF0MGZN7wk5 ....

How can I do that programmatically ?
thxs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use API level 8 or copy the base 64 class, which you can find here: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html

base64String is a String representing the picture in a base64 format. ImageView is your imageview which you want the picture to be shown in. The String you posted earlier.

Then you just can use this snippet:

```
    byte[] buf = Base64.decode(base64String,0);

    BitmapFactory factory = new BitmapFactory();
    Bitmap bitmap = factory.decodeByteArray(buf, 0, buf.length);
    ImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```